# How to avoid directly pass the recaptcha v3 site key into script tag of index.html

Tags: blazor, hosted-blazor-webassembly

Implemented recaptcha v3 into blazor webassembly by placing recaptcha script tags in index.html page. but when i view source code from browser the site html page visible to everyone which contains site key in script tage. may i know how to overcome this.

Implemented recaptcha v3 into blazor webassembly by placing recaptcha script tags in index.html page. but when i view source code from browser the site html page visible to everyone which contains site key in script tage.i don't want to display my site to end user. thanks

Comment: this is the second question of yours that I have seen where you are trying to hide the basic building blocks of the web. If you are going to build client-side apps, then you should start to get comfortable with the fact that everything on the client side is visible in the browser. Of course you need to be wary of giving away any secret keys, so you should definitely exercise caution. But recaptcha keys are not secrets - the google docs even recommend putting them in the HTML. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: So I will ask the same question to you on this question as I did on the other question. WHY do you want to hide the key? I'm not saying you don't have a good reason, but I just want to understand your motivation.

Comment: sry, it is site key only. Same like that I thought it would cause any problem to application. Since I am new to this development. I want to make sure these things are ok. understood. Thanks for your time and clarification.

Comment: No problem. It is better to be on the safer side. It is only right that you have all these questions at the start. As long as you are following good examples (the google docs in this case), you should be fine. First and foremost enjoy the learning process. Unless you are making your app public and storing sensitive data, I would focus more on enjoying the process of building an app right now.